# Pasar un arreglo al metodo find de un modelo laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una declaración que se encarga de obtener los paquetes mediante un $id y el metodo find() del modelo:

```
$package = Package::find($array);
    $package->each(function($package)
    {
        $package->type;
        $package->days;
        $package->hotels;
    });
```

Esto funciona perfecto, me devuelve la información de cada id del $array.

El $array contiene los valores [1,2,3....] por lo que me devuelve la informacion de los paquetes con sus respectivos id, por cuestiones de filtros, me gustaria agregar una clausula where, pero al usar el siguente metodo:

```
$package = Package::where('id' = $array)
                    ->where('starts_at', '<=', '2017-06-07');
    $package->each(function($package)
    {
        $package->type;
        $package->days;
        $package->hotels;
    });
```

No me devuelve nada...

¿Alguien sabe como podría pasarle cada uno de los id del arreglo y obtener sus respectivos datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta agregar el método get() para ejecutar la consulta y corregir la sintaxis del primer where, cambiándolo por un whereIn para que acepte el array:

```
$package = Package::whereIn('id', $array)
    ->where('starts_at', '<=', '2017-06-07')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Funcionó a la perfección!